# Let A and B be subsets of a topological space (X, τ). Prove that $\overline{A\cap B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$

Tags: general-topology, neighbourhood

Hi I was working on the following problem :

[image]

I have some kind of intuition why this would be (tough I might be wrong) :

We can break up the $ \overline{A \cap B} $ into $ A \cap B$ and all L the set of all the limit points of $ A \cap B$.

The second set exist out of the closure over A and the closure over B. Those we again can split up into A and $L_A$ the set of limit points of A. The same can be done for B into B and $L_B$.

Thus we can replace $\overline{A\cap B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ by  $ (A\cap B)\cup L \subseteq (A\cup L_A)\cap(B\cup L_B)$ We can work out the left part of the equation : $(A\cap B)\cup L \subseteq (A\cap B)\cup(L_A \cap L_B)\cup(L_A \cap B)\cup (L_B \cap A)$ and then we can eliminate $(A\cap B)$ from both sides : $ L \subseteq (L_A \cap L_B)\cup(L_A \cap B)\cup (L_B \cap A)$

Is my proof correct up to here? How can I proof the remaining statement?
It belonged to the section neighborhoods but I'm not quiet sure where the connection lies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prove that $E\subseteq F \implies \overline{E}\subseteq\overline{F}$. The inclusion follows from this

Comment: Sorry what are E and F?

Comment: @JipHelsen Any two subsets of $X$.  For instance, we could consider $E = A\cap B$ and $F = A$.

Comment: lol I just saw how trivial it becomes after that thx!]

Comment: why is this subset or equal actually can anybody give an example where this is just a subset? btw if you make your statement into an answer with an example why it is a subset I will approve

Comment: Find two disjoint subsets with a common limit point.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $x \in \overline{A \cap B}$, we have that for every open neighborhood U of $x$, $U \cap (A \cap B) \ne \emptyset. $ The proof follow from that.